# Access Express app within Express Router

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an ExpressJS application that uses several routers. Here is the basic form of the main app that ties everything together.

```
var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes/index');

var app = express();
app.set('someKey', someObj);


app.use('/', routes);

module.exports = app;
```

I have removed most of the code for brevity.

In that ./routes/index.js file I have defined a Express Router in the form:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'Express Test' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

I have attempted to use the following to access "somekey" from inside the router:

```
var app = require('../app');
var foo = app.get('somekey');
```

This crashes and burns with the runtime informing me that there is no such method get for app (further investigation yields that app is just a default Object).

I assume I am overlooking something that is completely obvious.

I plan to be passing a single knexjs object to each of the routers that deal with database calls. In the code's current state it is duplicated across each of the routers. I'd like to have it defined once in the main app and then be used by all of the routers such that if a change is made in the main app it is reflected across the routers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you require the `app` that way, you are not exactly referring to the app object you defined in your `app.js`. Instead, you are asking for whatever that file exported. To get what you want to achieve, may use something like this.

In your app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express(); // Note the switched order

app.set('someKey', someObj);

var routes = require('./routes/index')(app);
app.use('/', routes);

module.exports = app;
```

Then in your routes:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* Wrap everything inside a function */
module.exports = function(app){

    console.log(app.get('someKey')); // Access app passed to it from app.js

    /* Declare all your routes here. app variable will be accessible */
    router.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.render('index', { title: 'Express Test' });
    });

    return router;
};
```

Basically, whenever you are requiring a file B from A and want to pass a variable from A to B, this is the general pattern you follow.

See if if helps. :)